# Linq To NHibernate: .StartsWith on multiple properties

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, startswith

I'm trying to accomplish the following query (notice .StartsWith):

```
return (from p in _session.Linq<Profile>()
        where (p.Firstname + " " + p.Lastname).StartsWith(wildcard)
        select p).ToList();
```

This throws: could not resolve property: Firstname.Lastname.

If I do this:

```
return (from p in _session.Linq<Profile>()
        where p.Firstname.StartsWith(wildcard)
        select p).ToList();
```

Everything is working. How can this be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated - what are you trying to do? Select all `Profile` that the name starts with something?

Comment: I'm trying to select all Profile where Firstname and Lastname (concat'ed) is equal to wildcard.

Comment: Your corrected code runs and compiles, but you say it throws, can you show the stacktrace? See also my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Where` `Expression` does not know how to handle the concatenation of strings. It is trying to make sense of the properties, not the values.

Also, for future reference the StartsWith with the concat and the other one with out would in practice return the same thing.

Is this what you want?

```
return (from p in _session.Linq<Profile>()
        where p.Firstname.StartsWith(wildcard) || p.Lastname.StartsWith(wildcard)
        select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Allright, that makes sense!

But if I can't do it this way, do you have another way to accomplish what I wanna do?

Comment: that wont work. FirstName is say "Ram" and LastName is say "Lal". What if i search for "Ram Lal". This would not give you result.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** rewritten answer based on new insights and edited questions.

What's in `wildcard` and what's the expected output vs. input? If you concat `"Abel" + " " + "Braaksma"` it will return true for `wildcard.StartsWith("Abel")` or `wildcard.StartsWith("Abel Br")` but not `wildcard.StartsWith("Braaks")`. Do you perhaps mean `Contains` instead? But this won't solve your error:

*The exception you receive seems to come from NHibernate, not from your code. Is it possible that `Lastname` does not have a correct mapping to the database table? Can you show the stacktrace? Can you access the properties outside of the context of the LINQ statement, but filled with data from the table?*

Comment: Allright, I got a little further. I'm nearly convinced that the error is because of a bug in Linq to NHibernate. When the query is "converted" by L2NHibernate it is actually requesting Firstname.Lastname instead of concatenating the two properties.